# Расположение картинки по центру и текста снизу без смещений и перекрытий при разной длине текста в xml android

Tags: android, xml, вёрстка, ui

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/secondContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/firstContainer">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLinearContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/newsContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/news_block_gradient"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="showNewsSubcategories" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/newsImageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/pink_big" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/MainBlocksText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/newsImageView"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/news_block_text"
                    android:id="@+id/newsText" />


            </RelativeLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/catalogueContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/catalogue_block_gradient"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="showCataloguesSubcategories" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/catalogueImageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/katalog" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/MainBlocksText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/catalogueImageView"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/catalogue_block_text"
                    android:id="@+id/catalogueText" />


            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Кто знает, как сделать так что бы картинки "Лупа" и "Чашка" были на одном уровне. Просто изза того что в TextView"обзор заведений" текст не влезает в оражневый блок по ширине, и параметр gravity = "center" картинка ползет вверх

Comment: Оставьте в вопросе верстку только ячейки, коя не так работает, как хочется. Остальное - лишнее и мешает.

Comment: возможно вам подойдет [`PercentRelativeLayout`](http://www.androidauthority.com/using-the-android-percent-support-library-630715/) из библиотеки поддержки *support:design*. Виджет позволяет указать процентное соотношение занимаемого вложенными виджетами места.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Изменил, две верних ячейки в одном LinearLayout, для того что бы они делили ширину дисплея по полам, нужно что бы картинки в верхних ячейках были на одном уровне,

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо, не знал про такую либу)

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал вам просто придумать названия покороче, вроде "заведения", потому что выглядеть все равно будет кособоко, если везде одна строка, а в одном квадрате - две